# Why does pyInstaller packed program creates guardian when creating a new process on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, pyinstaller

I am trying to write an *alarm clock* program in python using multiprogramming module on Windows 7.

It all runs good in the interpreter. But when packed in one file by `pyinstaller`, every time the code create a process, there turn out to be 2 processes, one is a parent and the other is its child. When the code kills the parent process, the child become an orphan process.

The code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,freeze_support
import time
import winsound

def startout(seconds,name):
    freeze_support()
    print name+':pid '+str(os.getpid())+' is created'
    startTime=time.time()
    while (time.time()-startTime)<seconds:
        time.sleep(1)
    winsound.PlaySound('SystemQuestion', winsound.SND_ALIAS)
    print name+' end'

class alarmCenter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.alarmList={'alarm1':None,'alarm2':None,'alarm3':None}

    def newAlarm(self,seconds,name):
        if self.alarmList[name]!=None:
            if self.alarmList[name].is_alive():
                return False
        ala=Process(target=startout, args=(seconds,name))
        ala.deamon=True
        ala.start()
        self.alarmList[name]=ala
        return True

    def stopAlarm(self,name):
        try:
            self.alarmList[name].terminate()
            self.alarmList[name].join()
            self.alarmList[name]=None
        except Exception:
            pass

    def terminateAll(self):
        for each in self.alarmList.keys():
            if self.alarmList[each]!=None:
                self.alarmList[each].terminate()
    if __name__=='__main__':
        freeze_support()
        #....
```

Note that `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` is already there.

Could anyone please show me how to kill the child process or fix this bug?